# CCRenderTexture not making a perfect copy (cocos2d)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am having a problem with CCRenderTexture:

[image: screenshot]

The item on the left is the "copy" .. on the right is the original.  I use the code below to try to create and EXACT copy of the sprite/png on the right.

But when I create a sprite from the CCRenderTexture below ... I am losing the drop shadows and the the image looks a bit smudged ... should be an exact copy.

Any ideas?
Am I using CCRenderTexture incorrectly?
Why the difference?

```
//Sprite on the right
CCSprite* hack = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ColumnMatchCheck.png"];
hack.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);

CCRenderTexture* render = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:hack.contentSize.width
                                                           height:hack.contentSize.height
                                                      pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];


[render beginWithClear:1 g:1 b:1 a:0];
[render.sprite setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA}];

[hack visit];
[render end];

//Sprite on the left
CCSprite* test2 = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:render.sprite.texture];
```

Comment: different blend modes pethaps. Render texture is known to not create 100% exact copies.

Comment: But there must be some way to match the blend modes programmatically to what is being rendered to screen???

Comment: yes by applying the blendmode used by all the elements drawn to it. But there's still the issue of rendertexture "squeezing" the texture by a few pixels, so the copy will probably never be 100% accurate unless this issue has been fixed since.

Comment: Do you have any example code of how to get the best possible match?  I don't understand your comment "applying the blend mode used by all the elements drawn to it".  Could you elaborate or suggest some code to look at?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: try taking the blendFunc property from ccsprite code and assign that to rendrtexture's blendFunc. Might work.